# How to recreate project root source folder in TFS

Tags: version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I accidentally destroyed (i.e. tf destroy) my TFS project's source control root folder.  Is there a way that this folder can be recreated?  The new folder button is disabled when I right-click on the Collection root.  I don't want to have to recreate the project because I already have work items in there that I would lose.

Please note that I don't want to try to recover the files that were destroyed.  I understand that those files are gone forever which is what I wanted. I just want to recreate the project's root source control folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neno Loje created a command line app for this

http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2010/11/03/how-to-add-a-source-control-folder-to-an-existing-team-project.aspx